# PHP WordPress Plugin - How to display a div on the static homepage only?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my first time building a plugin for WordPress. I got the basics down but now I am trying to display a *div* on the bottom right corner, more like a small pop-up on the bottom right side of the front page only. The PHP code that I've uploaded did not work, it kept crashing my website.

> Where is my mistake?

Please explain your answers. Thank you!

**Code:**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My First Plugin
Plugin URL: http://www.martinshabacom.ipage.com/test
Description: An awesome facebook popup plugin that will amaze you!
Author: Martin
Version: 1.0
Author URL: http://www.martinshabacom.ipage.com/test
*/
add_action('admin_menu', 'myfirstplugin_admin_actions');
function myfirstplugin_admin_actions() {
    add_options_page('MyFirstPlugin', 'MyFirstPlugin', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'myfirstplugin_admin');
}

function myfirstplugin_admin()
{
?>
<style>
    .wrap { 
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        }

    .popup {
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        width:325px;
        height:200px;
        background-color:#09f;
    }
</style>


    <div class="wrap">

    <h1>Hello World!</h1><br>
    <h4>Hope you like my awesome popup!</h4>

    </div>



<?php if(is_front_page()) {
        <div class="popup">Testing Div Tag On The Bottom Right Corner...</div>
    }
?>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: When you say, "[...]kept crashing my website", what do you mean? Have you checked the Apache error log for output which might relate?

Comment: When I delete the plugin files, my website comes back up! 
What I meant was that it showed the 500 error something.

Comment: I suggest reviewing the Apache error log to find the cause. Further, is important to take note of the exact error code (not "500 error something").

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: @Nathan Do you even know if my code is written correctly?

Comment: That sounds like the error which is returned to the web client. What you need to understand what is going on is review of the error being reported by Apache/PHP. This would be output to an error log located on the server. My preference is to login to server and review over an SSH connection, but typically control panel hosting plans will also offer some alternate method of reviewing the Apache error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following part should not be inluded the PHP `if` clause..

```
<div class="popup">Testing Div Tag On The Bottom Right Corner...</div>
```

Generally I think it's better to use alternative syntax to make your code more readable:

```
<?php if (...) : ?> 
      your html code
<?php endif; ?>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: how would I echo out the div to the front page? what would I put inside the "your html code"